# Missing desktop app icon

Tags: gnome, icons, .desktop

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and have a custom desktop file for ST:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=st
GenericName=Terminal
Comment=standard terminal emulator for the X window system
Exec=st -t "st" -f "Source Code Pro:style=Semibold:size=18" -g "80x24"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Icon=utilities-terminal
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
```

For some reason I always get an "icon don't exist" icon.

[image: dead icon]

Other applications that use `utilities-terminal` as an icon parameter show it so this is very strange. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Is the icon wrong only in the dock? If you search for "st" in Activities overview, do you see the correct icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the path of your app icon, as the value of the directive `Icon`.

`Icon=/home/username/Documents/youapp/youricon.png`

Comment: I tried a full path, it didn't help at all. The icon works in the favorite and the app folder, but not on my Desktop!?

Answer (score -1):

1. Use the shortcut key Ctrl+Alt+t to open the terminal window on the Ubuntu desktop.
2. Then the system monitor window opens; Click the search button in the upper right corner to find "Nautilus".
3. Next, right click on the "Nautilus" process to "end the process".
4. Now, once again, Ctrl+Alt+t reopens a terminal window command to open the file management software.

   Enter:

   ```
    nohup  nautilus  &
   ```

Comment: Could you please explain what those steps/commands do (and why they would solve OP's issue here)?

Comment: If this is how you refresh the Nautilus, I think that the F5 key is enough...